# Sql select count to python code

Tags: python, sql, django

I want to know if there's a possible way to do the functionality of this select in Python, I want to know the diagnostic that is more reputed, but it can be in 3 different fields, I know that this select works, but I don't know how to put it in Python, or if there's any other what to do the same in Python.

```
SELECT Count(*)
 FROM   (
    SELECT DISTINCT
           imp_diagnostica_99
         , imp_diagnostica_100
         , imp_diagnostica_101
    FROM   expmedico_expedienteconsultainicial
   ) As distinctified
```

I want to get the procedure that the doctors sent more.

model.py

```
class AutorizacionImagenologia(models.Model):

imagenologia_fecha_solicitud_1 = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
imagenologia_fecha_emision = models.DateField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
tipo_plan = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=True, blank=True)
empresa_empleadora = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
imagenologia_hora_de_solicitud_2 = models.TimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
imagenologia_medico_solicita_3 =  models.ForeignKey(Medico, related_name='MedicoImagenologia', null=True)
imagenologia_nombre_pac_4 = models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=True)
imagenologia_apellido =  models.CharField(max_length=60, null=False, blank=True)
imagenologia_fecha_nacimiento_5 = models.DateField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
imagenologia_edad_miembro6 = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
imagenologia_sexo_7 = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
imagenologia_diagnostico_9 = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
imagenologia_credencial = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
imagenologia_procedimiento = models.ForeignKey(
        Estudios_Imagenologia,
        related_name='ProcedimientosImg', blank=True, null=True)
imagenologia_procedimiento2 = models.ForeignKey(Estudios_Imagenologia, related_name='ProcedimientosImg2', blank=True, null=True)
imagenologia_procedimiento3 =  models.ForeignKey(
        Estudios_Imagenologia, related_name='ProcedimientosImg3',
        blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use RawQuerySet with a custom model (used only for this sql), or use the connection cursor API:

```
from django.db import connection

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute('your_sql_here')
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        print 'row fields:', row[0], row[1], row[3]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Django and have a model expmedico_expedienteconsultainicial you can distinct that expmedico_expedienteconsultainicial objects:

```
expmedico_expedienteconsultainicial.objects.all().values('imp_diagnostica_99', 'imp_diagnostica_100','imp_diagnostica_101').distinct().count()
```

Please show your Django model and explain what you want to do with the resaults so that we can give you optimal answer.

Django's documentation for working with querysets https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/